# Is this possible to drag and drop a task from a User Story to another User Story in Task Board

Tags: rally

Currently I'm having a custom app extend from the Rally Legalcy taskboard (source code: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/legacy/TaskBoard.html)

With this task board, I'm able to drag a task from one state to another state (for example: from Define -> In Progress)

Now I would like to make it able to drag a task from one User Story to another User Story, is this possible and how to do that?

Thanks in advance.
Phuc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rally app catalog's github repo](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src) is split between legacy and new apps. New apps are based on [AppSDK2rc3](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/).

In a couple of weeks a new release of this AppSDK2 should be available. It will come with new TaskBoard written with AppSDK2.

This TaskBoard app is expected to be easily modified to allow vertical drag and drop of task cards across horizontal swim lanes, which represent user stories that own those tasks.

There will be a property `enableCrossRowDragging` on the`rowConfig` config object of `Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard`. Its default value is false, but you may set it to true to enable re-parenting of tasks. 
As you enable the dragging of task cards across rows, make sure that this action triggers the change of `WorkProduct` value of a Task. See [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) object model. Task object has a `WorkProduct` field, which is a reference to the artifact the task is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the property NickM mentioned above: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-cfg-rowConfig

And the new task board app source is available here:
https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/taskboard/TaskBoardApp.js#L242

If you just delete that linked line you should be able to drag tasks across rows.

We haven't made the official 2.0 GA announcement yet, but you should be able to use it now if you'd like!